# Помогите разобраться с кодом (Google Chart)

Tags: javascript, google-chart

Нашел подходящий для себя график на Google Chart, не могу понять как задавать значения даты, нужно выводить число.месяц.год

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);

function drawStacked() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

      data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Дождь');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Сухо');

      data.addRows([
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 заказов'}, 3, 5],
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 заказов'}, 2, 7],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'4 заказов'}, 2, 2],
        [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '11 заказов'}, 4, 7],
        [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 заказов'}, 2, 10],
        [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 заказов'}, 1, 0],
        [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 заказов'}, 2, 0],
        [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '5 заказов'}, 1, 4],
        [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 заказов'}, 2, 2],
        [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '15 заказов'}, 5, 10],
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: '',
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: {
          title: '',
          format: 'd.M.y',
          viewWindow: {
            min: [7, 30, 0],
            max: [17, 30, 0]
          }
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Кол-во заказов'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes

https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Time of Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Rating');

    data.addRows([
      [new Date(2015, 0, 1), 5],  [new Date(2015, 0, 2), 7],  [new Date(2015, 0, 3), 3],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 4), 1],  [new Date(2015, 0, 5), 3],  [new Date(2015, 0, 6), 4],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 7), 3],  [new Date(2015, 0, 8), 4],  [new Date(2015, 0, 9), 2],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 10), 5], [new Date(2015, 0, 11), 8], [new Date(2015, 0, 12), 6],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 13), 3], [new Date(2015, 0, 14), 3], [new Date(2015, 0, 15), 5],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 16), 7], [new Date(2015, 0, 17), 6], [new Date(2015, 0, 18), 6],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 19), 3], [new Date(2015, 0, 20), 1], [new Date(2015, 0, 21), 2],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 22), 4], [new Date(2015, 0, 23), 6], [new Date(2015, 0, 24), 5],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 25), 9], [new Date(2015, 0, 26), 4], [new Date(2015, 0, 27), 9],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 28), 8], [new Date(2015, 0, 29), 6], [new Date(2015, 0, 30), 4],
      [new Date(2015, 0, 31), 6], [new Date(2015, 1, 1), 7],  [new Date(2015, 1, 2), 9]
    ]);


    var options = {
      title: 'Rate the Day on a Scale of 1 to 10',
      width: 900,
      height: 500,
      hAxis: {
        format: 'M/d/yy',
        gridlines: {count: 15}
      },
      vAxis: {
        gridlines: {color: 'none'},
        minValue: 0
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);

    var button = document.getElementById('change');

    button.onclick = function () {

      // If the format option matches, change it to the new option,
      // if not, reset it to the original format.
      options.hAxis.format === 'M/d/yy' ?
      options.hAxis.format = 'MMM dd, yyyy' :
      options.hAxis.format = 'M/d/yy';

      chart.draw(data, options);
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде разобрался, осталься только вопрос, как сделать в вертикальной шкале шаг 1, вместо 0.5...

```js
 google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Дождь');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Сухо');

    data.addRows([
      [{v: new Date(2015, 0, 1), f: 'Всего заявок __'}, 5, 11],  
      [{v: new Date(2015, 1, 1), f: 'Всего заявок __'}, 15, 1],  
      [{v: new Date(2015, 2, 1), f: 'Всего заявок __'}, 5, 21],  
      [{v: new Date(2015, 3, 1), f: 'Всего заявок __'}, 15, 2],  
      [{v: new Date(2015, 4, 1), f: 'Всего заявок __'}, 5, 5],  
      [{v: new Date(2015, 5, 1), f: 'Всего заявок __'}, 5, 11],  
      [{v: new Date(2015, 6, 1), f: 'Всего заявок __'}, 15, 1],  
      [{v: new Date(2015, 7, 1), f: 'Всего заявок __'}, 5, 1],  
    ]);


    var options = {
   isStacked: true,
      width: 900,
      height: 500,
      hAxis: {
        format: 'dd/MM/y',
        gridlines: {count: 12}
      },
      vAxis: {
        gridlines: {color: 'none'},
        minValue: 0

      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);

  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
```